# Setting PyTorch to `train` or `eval` modes globally instead of at nn.Module level

Tags: pytorch

At PyTorch `model` that inherit from `torch.nn.Module` can be set to `train` or `eval` modes using `model.train()` or `model.eval()`.
Is there a way to do this globally for the present PyTorch session, so that it applies to any op that is invoked, without having to update different models?

This could be useful in running PyTorch scripts in training or inference context as desired.